# Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- i am new to react.
- i am trying to use ‘connect’ to get value from template reducer
- i am facing the below errors
  Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined
- can you tell me how to fix it
- providing the whole code in fiddle
  https://jsfiddle.net/bmfzLs3z/3/
- providing the snippet code below

  ```
  let ReservationCard =  React.createClass({
      propTypes: {
           value: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
           profile: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
           SPORTSDetails: React.PropTypes.shape({
               error: React.PropTypes.object,
               SPORTSId: React.PropTypes.number,
               SPORTSName: React.PropTypes.string,
               SPORTSAmount: React.PropTypes.number,
               SPORTSDate: React.PropTypes.string,
               isRetrieving: React.PropTypes.boolean
           }),
           onEdit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
       },

       displayName: 'ReservationCard',
    })

    export default connect(state => ({
        profile: state.template.profile,

    }), null, null, {
        withRef: true // allows parent to access component functions
    })(ReservationCard);
  ```

Comment: It worked before changing that line?

Comment: @John I am not getting the state....sorry that was my bad

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using connect? Do you have a redux store? state is probably undefined because by default state will be undefined if you don't have getInitialState implemented.

If you do have a redux store, note that it calls store.getState passing the value to your function. Your reducer might be returning null/undefined.